# How can I stop a FlexNativeMenu with keyEquivalents from stealing my keystrokes?

Tags: apache-flex, keystroke

I have a native menu item with a shortcut for a simple letter like "F".

```
<s:menu> 
    <mx:FlexNativeMenu id="mainMenu"
                       dataProvider="{menuData}"  
                       labelField="@label"  
                       keyEquivalentField="@keyEquivalent"  
                       showRoot="false" /> 
</s:menu> 

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML format="e4x" id="menuData"> 
        <root> 
            <menuitem label="Edit"> 
                <menuitem label="Frame Selection" keyEquivalent="f"/>
            </menuitem> 
        </root> 
    </fx:XML>
</fx:Declarations>
```

This works great, but when I try to type text in any textfield or textInput
anywhere in the app, I cant ever type f.

How can stop the menu from stealing my keyboard input ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better pattern to menu accelerators would use the control key, such as CTRL+F in your example.

Your menuitem would therefore include `controlKey="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:menu>
        <mx:FlexNativeMenu id="mainMenu"
                           dataProvider="{menuData}"
                           labelField="@label"
                           keyEquivalentField="@keyEquivalent"
                           showRoot="false" />
    </s:menu>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:XML format="e4x"
                id="menuData">
            <root>
                <menuitem label="Edit">
                    <menuitem label="Frame Selection"
                              keyEquivalent="f"
                              controlKey="true" />
                </menuitem>
            </root>
        </fx:XML>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:TextInput />

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: I am already using control key while I find a better solution, but would prefer to use f directly instead of control+f , I see no reason why the menuitem should stop the keyboard event instead of letting it bubble.

Comment: By specifying only "f", you are explicitly defining a powerful quick accelerator as a convenience per your design.  It is not logical to combine with text input operations.  However, I understand you are seeking a unique usability by stopping the immediate event propagation.

Comment: Nope - just more override of standard usability.